# Superuser cannot create or alter roles

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

Created a user/role via following method is Aurora Postgres:

```
CREATE ROLE rds_user_test;
GRANT rds_superuser to rds_user_test;
GRANT rds_iam TO rds_user_test;
```

When I login using IAM DB Auth as `rds_user_test` it appears that I can do all operations as needed except creating or altering roles (maybe other functionality is missing but haven't tested all operations yet). When I check role memberships of this new role against other roles that are able to create/alter roles, both are members of `superuser`.

I also followed the instructions here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-aurora-postgresql-clone-master-user/

Still get the same permissions error:

```
[42501] ERROR: permission denied to create role
```

Any thoughts on why this new role cannot create/alter other roles even though it seems to have the same privileges of superuser as other roles?

Comment: Please remember to disclose your version of Postgres. That can always play a role.

Comment: When you write *both are members of `superuser`*, you really mean `rds_superuser`, right?

Answer (score 2):

`rds_superuser` on Amazon Aurora is typically ***not*** a superuser. Check with:

```
SELECT rolsuper FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'rds_superuser';
```

But to create a role, you don't need superuser privileges. All you need is the `CREATEROLE` privilege. Check if your user has that:

```
SELECT rolcreaterole FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'rds_user_test';
```

Else you need to grant it (as a role that's allowed to do so):

```
ALTER ROLE rds_user_test CREATEROLE;
```

Any role with the `CREATEROLE` privilege can do that (typically including `rds_superuser`).
[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html#id-1.9.3.26.5)

> Roles having `CREATEROLE` privilege can change any of these settings except `SUPERUSER`, `REPLICATION`, and `BYPASSRLS`; but only for non-superuser and non-replication roles.

[The instructions you followed](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-aurora-postgresql-clone-master-user/), explicitly instruct to add `CREATEROLE`, you seem to have skipped that bit:

> ```
> CREATE ROLE new_master WITH PASSWORD 'password' CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN;
> ```

Comment: thanks, I did the instruction but without `LOGIN`. Which i did not think was necessary. But works when adding LOGIN. I am still not clear why LOGIN is needed for CREATEROLE to work?

Comment: @kravb: You wrote: *"When I login ... as `rds_user_test` ..."* This is impossible if the role is created without `LOGIN`. So there must be some kind of misunderstanding. Maybe you really used `CREATE USER` which implies `LOGIN`?